# wsimport not generating type class

Tags: java, soap-client, webservice-client, wsimport

I have the following element in my web service request and used `wsimport` to generate client. I also have other `enum` types which get classes generated. As this particular type contains values like **1-Critical** I think it fails to generate enum type but treats it as String.

```
    <xsd:element type="s0:UrgencyType" name="Urgency" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

   <xsd:simpleType name="UrgencyType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="1-Critical"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="2-High"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="3-Medium"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="4-Low"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
```

The generated parameter as below.

```
@WebParam(name = "Urgency", targetNamespace = "urn:GIL:Create_WS")
        String urgency,
```

I want the variable urgency type to be **UrgencyType**.

Comment: Usually you get an `enum` with the enumeration values as constants. A guess: Since your enumeration values start with a digit (which is an illegal character for the start of a variable or constant name), the `wsimport` command falls back to a simple `String`.

Comment: Is it ok to create and change the parameter to UrgencyType manually?